# Charging capacitor, with series and parallel resisters

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, batteries

I understand how equations for charging capacitor are derived and what they represent. But here is my problem: if you want to experimentally see how voltage on capacitor changes with time, you have to make the circuit down below, the equations for charging capacitor is still valid when $R_1$ is much smaller than Voltmeter's resistor. But this isn't true if resistor $R_1$ is quite large compared to $R_2$.

My question: What is the equation that describes how voltage on charging capacitor is changing with respect to time, where resistor $R_1$ isn't very small compared to $R_2$.

I don't want just equation pasted in the answer section, I want the explanation how to derive it, and explanation of steps which have to be taken to get there.

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start we find the voltage drop across resistor $R_2$ with no capacitor present, this will give us the voltage that the capacitor will charge to when reaching steady state. The voltage drop across $R_2$ is

$$V_0=V_T\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2},$$

where $V_T$ is the voltage of the battery. Then we write down the rate equation for the voltage across a charging capacitor, this can be written

$$\dot{V}(t)=A_1\left(V_T-V(t)\right)-A_2V(t),$$

the first positive term is due to the capacitor charging through the resistor $R_1$, which is proportional to the difference of the maximum voltage and the acquired voltage during charging. The second negative term is due to the capacitor simultaneously discharging through resistor $R_2$. Solving the rate equation gives

$$V(t)=\frac{A_1V_T}{A_1+A_2}\left(1-e^{-(A_1+A_2)t}\right),$$

the coefficients $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the normal time constants for a capacitor in series with a resistor $A_{1,2}=1/R_{1,2}C$. Substituting this into the above and the expression for $V_0$ gives

$$V(t)=V_0\left(1-e^{-\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1R_2C}t}\right).$$

For $R_2\gg R_1$, it can be seen that we obtain the standard equation for the voltage across a capacitor in series with a resistance $R_1$ as a function of the time.

Comment: @relayman357  That’s correct, I’ve edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jamie1989, what other circuits will your method work to solve?  Just those with one storage element (e.g. 1 cap or 1 inductor)?  Just wondering if this is only useful in few cases or more widely.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this circuit with the same [differential equation approach](http://physics.bu.edu/%7Eduffy/semester2/c11_RC.html) you would for the simpler RC circuit.  Just grit your teeth and work through the math.  I prefer to work transients problems like this using the [Laplace Transform method](https://www.ee.nthu.edu.tw/%7Esdyang/Courses/Circuits/Ch13_Std.pdf).  The circuit is transformed to the frequency domain, solved, and then inverse transformed back to the time domain.

In your example, the battery voltage V converts to a voltage source with amplitude $\frac{V}{s}$.  The capacitor converts to an impedance of $\frac{1}{sC}$.  $R_1$ and $R_2$ are unchanged.  "s" is the Laplace Transform operator.  Once you have the Laplace Transform circuit you solve it with all the normal electrical circuit techniques.

[image]

The capacitor and $R_2$ in parallel can be lumped together in an equivalent impedance of,
$$\frac{\frac{R_2}{sC}}{R_2+\frac{1}{sC}}$$

From that we can find $I(s)$ as,
$$I(s)=\frac{\frac{V}{s}}{R_1+\frac{\frac{R_2}{sC}}{R_2+\frac{1}{sC}}}$$

Working through the algebra this becomes,
$$I(s)=V\frac{\frac{1}{R_1}(s+\frac{1}{R_2C})}{s^2+s(\frac{1}{R_1C}+\frac{1}{R_2C})}$$

You can work this into a common [Laplace Transform pair](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/Common%20Laplace%20Transform%20Pairs.pdf), or you can reduce it using [partial fraction expansion](https://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/laplace/pf/pf.html).  Either way, you are putting into a form that can be transformed back into time domain.  I just used the `invLaplace` operator in MathCad to get the solution,

$${\mathscr{L}}^{-1}I(s) = i(t) = V\frac{R_1+R_2e^{-\frac{t(R_1+R_2)}{CR_1R_2}}}{R_1(R_1+R_2)} $$

If you look at the above it makes sense.  Assuming the capacitor is completely discharged when the switch is thrown to connect the battery, the initial current (t=0+) is only restricted by $R_1$ and will be amplitude $V/R_1$.  After the capacitor is substantially charged, its voltage will equal the voltage dropped across $R_2$ and the current from the battery will be $V/(R_1+R_2)$.

If are interested in the transient voltage across the capacitor, one approach is to take the $I(s)$ we found above and multiply it times the impedance of the $C$ and $R_2$ parallel combination,

$$I(s)(\frac{\frac{R_2}{sC}}{R_2+\frac{1}{sC}})$$

Then carefully work through the math to inverse transform back to the time domain as described above.  Doing this in MathCad I get the following for the voltage across the capacitor, $V_C(t)$,

$$V_C(t)=-\frac{VR_2[e^\frac{-t(R_1+R_2)}{CR_1R_2}-1]}{R_1+R_2}$$

From this you can see that initially (t=0) the voltage will be zero, and after the capacitor is substantially charged it will be $\frac{VR_2}{R_1+R_2}$ which is just voltage division ignoring the fully charged capacitor.

To put some numbers to it, let $R_1=500k\Omega$, $R_2=5M\Omega$, $V=50V$, and $C=100μF$ and we find,

$$i(t) = \frac{e^{\frac{-11t}{500}}}{11,000}+\frac{1}{110,000}$$
and
$$V_C(t)=\frac{500}{11}-\frac{500e^{\frac{-11t}{500}}}{11}$$

From this you can see that the voltage across the capacitor is initially zero, and eventually 45.455 V.

Here are a couple more examples of solving electrical transients circuits using Laplace:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525974/equation-20-16-proof/527788#527788

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531287/closed-form-solution-for-capacitor-charged-with-current-source-and-discharged-th